# place divs next to each other and one below

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to coding and I am trying to make a contact form with the Flex property so that I can place my "name" and "telephone number" horizontally next to each other and my "message" below. They must all be the same width. 
I can´t figure it out with CSS.

below is my HTML code:

```
<div class="contactcontainer">
  <form action="">
    <div class="input">
      <p>First name</p>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">


      <p>Phone number</p>
      <input type="text" name="pnumber" placeholder="your phone number">
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>Your message</p>
      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="type your message">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `flexbox`.

And remember to use semantic markup for your forms, e.g. use `label` for labels instead of `p` tag.

```css
.contactcontainer label {
  display: block;
}

.input {
  display: flex;
}

.input > div {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactcontainer">
  <form action="">
      <div class="input">
          <div>
            <label for="firstname">First name</label>
            <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">  
          </div>
          
          <div>
            <label for="pnumber">Phone number</label>
            <input id="pnumber" type="text" name="pnumber" placeholder="your phone number">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
          <label for="message">Your message</label>
          <textarea id="message" type="text" name="message" placeholder="type your message"></textarea>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jonas.D, you're welcome! Don't forget to choose a correct answer for the question so it can be marked as archived.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, Its not perfect, but it will give u starting point

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contactcontainer {
  width: 500px;
}

.input {
  display: flex;
}

.message input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.l,
.r {
  flex: 1;
}

.l input,
.r input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactcontainer">
  <form action="">
    <div class="input">
      <div class="l">
        <p>First name</p>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">

      </div>
      <div class="r">
        <p>Phone number</p>
        <input type="text" name="pnumber" placeholder="your phone number">
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>Your message</p>
      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="type your message">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve it using flex then

```css
   
.input { display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; }
```

```html
<div class="contactcontainer">
            <form action="">
                <div class="input">
                  <div class="inline">
                    <p>First name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="inline">
                    <p>Phone number</p>
                    <input type="text" name="pnumber" placeholder="your phone number">
                 </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                    <p>Your message</p>
                    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="type your message">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `FlexBox`

```css
.input {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  
  width: 100%;
}

.hor{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactcontainer">
  <form action="">
    <div class="input">
      <div class="hor">
        <p>First name</p>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">

      </div>
      <div class="hor">
        <p>Phone number</p>
        <input type="text" name="pnumber" placeholder="your phone number">
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>Your message</p>
      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="type your message">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Use `type=Number` for number validation

```css
.input {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  
  width: 100%;
}

.hor{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactcontainer">
  <form action="">
    <div class="input">
      <div class="hor">
        <p>First name</p>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">

      </div>
      <div class="hor">
        <p>Phone number</p>
        <input type="number" name="pnumber" placeholder="your phone number" min=1>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>Your message</p>
      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="type your message">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```